# Как сделать форму

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать такую форму в bootstrap. Есть, где это можно будет прочитать. Весь гугл перегуглил. Ничего не нашёл по этой теме.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Что именно нужно сделать и причём здесь бутстрап?

Comment: Поясняю. Я так полагаю это форма написана на бутстрапе. Может и нет. Мне бы хотелось научиться верстать , такие формы. Как это делать и куда смотреть.

Comment: @zagazat, ну как же не понятно. Человеку надо сделать такую линейную форму используя bootstrap. Но при этом, он не показывает что попытался сделать.

Comment: @R3D3 попробуйте сделать это без бутстрапа и выложите на jsfiddle ваш код. бутстрап здесь особо то роли не играет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то в таком роде, подстроить под себя css и будет отлично.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('li > a > span.text-primary').text($(this).val());
});
```

```css
* {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.bg-orange {
  background: #f4a442 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container py-3">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Город вылета: <span class="font-weight-bold text-primary"></span></a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item bg-orange">
      <a class="nav-link text-white bg-orange font-weight-bold" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Горячие туры <span class="badge badge-pill text-danger badge-light">-50%</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">

      <form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-4 border-right-0 pr-0">
            <select class="form-control border-right-0">
              <option disabled selected>Выбирете город</option>
              <option>Киев</option>
              <option>Москва</option>
              <option>Лондон</option>
              <option>Париж</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 p-0">
            <input type="date" class="form-control border-right-0" placeholder="Date">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 p-0">
            <input type="number" class="form-control border-right-0" placeholder="Кол-во пассажиров">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 p-0">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block bg-orange font-weight-bold text-white">Искать</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      Тут ещё что-то
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

```css
form {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">

      <form class="form-inline" action="#">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="country" class="form-control" placeholder="Страна" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Дата вылета" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="Кол-во ночей" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="Кто поедет" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Искать</button>
      </form>

    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      Горящие туры
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```